# excetude a function if after a other function if

Tags: javascript, html

My Problem is: I want to execute a if-loop only if before a other if-loop is executed.And both if-loop are in differnet functions.

```
function DoubleClicker() {
    var p = document.getElementById("p1");
    var Variable = document.getElementById('Variable');

        if (counter > 20) {
                p.innerHTML = DoubleClickerMinus();
                Variable.innerHTML = "True";
} else {
        window.alert("Zu wenige kekse");
    }
}


function add(){
    var Variable = document.getElementById("Variable");
    if (Variable = "True") {
        return counter += 2;
    } else {
        return counter += 1;
    }
}
```

only if the first function if are exectuted should the second function if are exectuted
i hope its understandable

ps: i am still student and not the best in englisch so pls forgive me misstakes in the text :D

**EDIT 1:**
i want that after the if-loop in the doubleclicker function the if part from the add function be addresed and normaly if the if loop not addresed that than the else be adressed. i hop its not to badly expressed

**EDIT 2:**
Now it works thanks for the help

Comment: Where/how are you calling the second function?

Comment: Just call the `add` function from within the `if` of the `DoubleClicker` function then.

Answer (score -1):

Just call **add** function inside the **if** Condition as below.

```js
function DoubleClicker() {
    var p = document.getElementById("p1");
    var Variable = document.getElementById('Variable');

        if (counter > 20) {
                p.innerHTML = DoubleClickerMinus();
                Variable.innerHTML = "True";
                add(); // call from here
} else {
        window.alert("Zu wenige kekse");
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want that after the if-loop in the doubleclicker function the if part from the add function be addresed and normaly if the if loop not addresed that than the else be adressed. i hop its not to badly expressed